# Javascript return statement inside filter function, get uniques. Why code works?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, unique

I have a big array of objects where I need to get the unique values for some keys.
I have the code working, but I would like to understand it.

Object

```
{
"cor": {
    "id": 89,
    "code": "192"
},
"tamanho": {
    "id": 74,
    "code": "L"
},
"price": "56,34",
"prevPrice": "93,90",
"stock": 0
}
```

And this is the iteration that return only unique values.
What I can't understand is the return statement, how does javasacript reads it?

```
var tamanhos = [];
data.grelha.filter(function(el, i, arr) {
  return tamanhos.indexOf(el.tamanho.id) == -1 && tamanhos.push(el.tamanho.id);
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Go read the documentation + filter is already returning a new array. You do not have to use `push`

Comment: if you like this style, use an object instead as hash table.

Comment: @Weedoze easy, my friend. Don't get hurt with a question..

Comment: Aside from mis-using `.filter()`, your example is a bit unclear given `data` and `grelha` are not shown anywhere. Anyway, regarding what the `return` statement does, in your case it does nothing of use because you ignore the return value from the `.filter()` function.

Comment: data.grelha is an array of objects just like the one I posted..

Comment: Please read some [documentation for `.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and let us know if you still don't understand how `.filter()` is supposed to work.

Comment: if anyone has something useful to say, I would really appreciate as I don't understand the return statement. Reading the docs is something I have obviously done, and, despite the misuse of filter, is not what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: You could get some insight in the code by debugging it.

Answer (score 2):

Before I get to what I *think* you're asking, let's talk about [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Firstly, it returns a new array, so calling `.filter()` without using its return value is not how you are supposed to use it: if you just want to iterate over the array you should use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead. It works by calling the function you pass it once per array element. Only elements for which your function returns a truthy value will be added to the output array. The *correct* way to use `.filter()` to solve this problem would be something like this:

```
var tamanhos = data.grelha.map(el) { return el.tamaho.id }).filter(function(el, i, arr) {
  return arr.indexOf(el) === i
})
```

That is, first use `.map()` to get a list of all the IDs, then use `.filter()` to only keep elements if they are the *first* occurrence of that ID in the array, thus setting `tamanhos` to be an array of unique IDs.

**Now to what you seem to be asking**, which is for an explanation of what the following line is doing:

```
return tamanhos.indexOf(el.tamanho.id) == -1 && tamanhos.push(el.tamanho.id);
```

The key is the [`&&` (logical AND) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). It uses [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), which means that the expression on the right-hand-side of the `&&` will only be evaluated if the expression on the left-hand-side is truthy.

Two simple examples (click "Run"):

```js
true && alert('This WILL display because alert() is called.');
false && alert('This will NOT display because alert() is not called');
```

So if `tamanhos.indexOf(el.tamanho.id) == -1` *is* true then the `tamanhos.push(el.tamanho.id)` part will be executed, otherwise the `.push()` will *not* be executed. In other words, the part after the `return` is equivalent to doing this:

```
if (tamanhos.indexOf(el.tamanho.id) == -1) {
  tamanhos.push(el.tamanho.id);
}
```

(That is, if the item isn't already in the `tamanhos` array then add it.)

The result of the whole `&&` expression is then returned, but as mentioned above that is not really relevant because you don't use the return value from `.filter()`. So what your code is doing is equivalent to this:

```
var tamanhos = [];
data.grelha.forEach(function(el) {
  if (tamanhos.indexOf(el.tamanho.id) == -1) {
    tamanhos.push(el.tamanho.id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a json datas. Json values can use array. I think, you know arrays. So Arrays has multi areas. Like :
`[val1]`
`[val1, val2]`
`[val1, val2, val3]`
`[val1, val2, val3, .....]`

we can take values as column name. Example for c#:

`array[] names = new array["mesut", "joa"]`

you have javascript arrays